# css alignment breaks in ie7 but works elsewhere

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, cross-browser

Please see this page: https://tjandpals.com/howto-html

It looks normal in modern firefox, safari, chrome and internet explorer.

However- in ie7, it breaks the alignment...

Any clues to make this more compatible?

Answer (score 1):

you can use ie7 hack on given classes :

```
.leftAd {*top:60px}
.TopAd{*float:none;*width:600px}
```

this thing will work fine in ie7

Answer (score 0):

as a first little step (sorry, but currently I've only a little time) you could set the height of the #HowToLanding DIV to auto. This brings the tiles in the right position.

You could do something like this:

```
#HowToLanding { height: 550px; *height: auto; }
```

**Update:** ...and do the same for the #Footer

```
#Footer { height: 150px; *height: 150px; ... }
```

HTH,
--hennson

Answer (score 0):

Add yout `<div id="TopAd">...</div and <div id="TopAd">...</div>` indide the

```
<div id="HowToLanding">..</div>
```